# route socket RTM_GET RTA_NETMASK does not match routing table entry

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I have the following entry on my routing table:

```
tecik:ihsan $ netstat -rn -f inet6 | grep 2400:3700:61:4::/64
2400:3700:61:4::/64               2400:3700:60:4::2             UG       gif104
```

I did an RTM_GET request via routing socket and I managed to get the RTA_DST information correctly but RTA_NETMASK always return 0 although the routing table says it's /64.

How do i obtain the correct netmask entry.

The code:

```
 /* fill in request header */
pid = getpid();
buf = calloc(0, sizeof(char) * buflen);
rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *) buf;
rtm->rtm_version = RTM_VERSION;
rtm->rtm_flags = RTF_UP | RTF_GATEWAY;
rtm->rtm_addrs = RTA_DST | RTA_NETMASK;
rtm->rtm_type  = RTM_GET;
rtm->rtm_pid   = pid;
rtm->rtm_seq   = seq;

/* take the dst AFI and assume the rest are of the same AFI */
if (dst->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
    sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) (rtm + 1);
    memcpy(sin6, dst, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ((char *) sin6 + alignsa(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)));
    memcpy(sin6, mask, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ((char *) sin6 + alignsa(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)));
    rtm->rtm_msglen = (char *) sin6 - buf;
}

/* write to routing socket */
write(s, rtm, rtm->rtm_msglen);

/* now read the reply */
do {
    n = read(s, rtm, buflen);
} while (rtm->rtm_type != RTM_GET || rtm->rtm_seq != seq || rtm->rtm_pid != pid);

close(s);
/* cycle through all routing replies, checking for expected sockaddr */
rtm = (struct rt_msghdr *) buf;
sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) (rtm + 1);
for (rtax = 0; rtax < RTAX_MAX; rtax++) {
    if (rtm->rtm_addrs & (1 << rtax)) {
        sa = (struct sockaddr *) sin6;

        if (rtax == RTAX_DST) {
            al->rt = malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_ADDRSTR);
            getaddrstr(al->rt, sa);
        }
        else if (rtax == RTAX_NETMASK) {
            sa->sa_family = AF_INET6;
            al->rtplen    = getcidr(sa);
        }

        sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) (char *) sin6 + alignsa(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    }
}

if (al->rtplen == 0)
    def = 1;

if (def)
    debug("%s has default route, ignoring..", al->ifname);
else
    debug("%s has route %s/%u", al->ifname, al->rt, al->rtplen);

free(buf);
```

alignsa() is:

```
size_t
alignsa(size_t s)
{
    return (1 + (((s) - 1) | (sizeof(size_t) - 1)));
}
```

getcidr() is

```
/* all zeros netmask */
if (sa->sa_len == 0)
    return(plen);

switch (sa->sa_family) {
    case AF_INET:

        break;

    case AF_INET6:
        s = (uint8_t *) &((struct sockaddr_in6 *)sa)->sin6_addr;

        if (*s == 0)
            break;

        for (i = 0; ((i < 16) && (*s == 0xff)); i++, s++)
            plen += 8;

        break;

    default:
            return(-1);
}

return(plen);
```

If I print out the value of al->rt, it comes out as 2400:3700:61:4:: but rtplen is always 0.

If I print out the sockaddr_in6 for the netmask, it comes out exactly as ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:: or /64 so somehow I think for RTA_NETMASK, the sin6_len is 0 but I don't understand why.

Comment: I'd like to make a correction, when i print out the netmask value, it's shown as 0, not /64.

Comment: I'm actually on FreeBSD so I'm not privy to iproute facility.

Comment: I would like also to get the IPv6 route reading the information from the kernel, but I get EINVAL at the write call.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: This answer is wrong, since it only applies to netlink RTM_GETROUTE. The op was asking about routing sockets.**

I will assume you mean RTM_GETROUTE, even though your topic says RTM_GET. The RTM_GETROUTE does not return the same information, that is displayed by netstat -6 -rn. The command can return cached routes. Perhaps even more surprisingly, RTM_GETROUTE can **create** routes in the routing cache.

This is from the iproute2 documentation (on my Ubuntu its listed in *man 8 ip-route*):

> ```
>    Note that this operation is not equivalent to ip route show.  show
>    shows existing routes.  get resolves them and creates new clones if
>    necessary.  Essentially, get is equivalent to sending a packet along
>    this path.  If the iif argument is not given, the kernel creates a
>    route to output packets towards the requested destination.  This is
>    equivalent to pinging the destination with a subsequent ip route ls
>    cache, however, no packets are actually sent.  With the iif argument,
>    the kernel pretends that a packet arrived from this interface and
>    searches for a path to forward the packet.
> ```

In your case, you could compare the output of *ip -6 route show table all* and *ip -6 route get  2400:3700:60:4::123*. They will probably be a little different, with the *ip route get* version containing the word *cached* at the end.

Im currently at a location with no IPv6 connectivity, but this local route illustrates what I mean:

> thuovila@glx:~$ ip -6 r l table all |grep ff00::/8
>
> ff00::/8 dev eth1  table local  metric 256
>
> thuovila@glx:~$ ip r get ff00::/8
>
> ff00:: from :: via ff00:: dev eth1  src fe80::21b:b1ff:fe48:1a75  metric 0 
>       cache

As you noticed, the cached route does not contain a desitnation address length (netmask).

To solve your problem, (how to get the netmask) I suggest looking into filtering netlink messages. Instead of a single RTM_GET request you will have to dump routes matching your criteria and filter *cloned* routes. The iproute2 tools do this in e.g. the [iproute.c](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/shemminger/iproute2.git;a=blob_plain;f=ip/iproute.c;hb=HEAD) module with the function `static int filter_nlmsg`. It contains, among other things, a line saying `if (filter.cloned == !(r->rtm_flags&RTM_F_CLONED))` which removes cloned (i.e. originating from the cache) routes. It is called by `route_print()` to limit which routes are shown. Routes are, in the *ip route list* command, dumped with a call to libnetlink function `rtnl_dump_filter()`.

For further tips on how to use netlink, inspect the sources of iproute2, especially the *ip/iproute.c* and *lib/libnetlink.c* modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to resolve the issue, it turns out that I did not properly cast the buffer back to sockaddr_in6 on the main function:

```
sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) (char *) sin6 + alignsa(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
```

while it should have been:

```
sin6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *) ((char *) sin6 + alignsa(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6)));
```

By casting everything on the right of the first sockaddr_in6 cast and also to remove the RTA_NETMASK request from the rt_msghdr struct, I've managed to return the correct netmask information.

So it's all good now.